# Codeigniter Active Record / MySQL Query - group_by causes only one row to be returned

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, group-by

I have the following query:

```
$this->db
     ->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS null as rows
        ,services.*
        ,service_categories.*
        ,categories.*
        ,table4.*', FALSE)
     ->from('services')
     ->where('services.user_id', $user_id)
     ->join('service_categories', 'service_categories.service_id = services.service_id')
     ->join('categories', 'categories.cat_id= service_categories.cat_id')
     ->join('table4', 'table4.service_id= services.service_id', 'left')
     ->group_by('services.service_id')
     ->order_by('services.service_id', 'DESC');

 $query = $this->db->get();
```

The tables look like this:

```
Table: services
------------------------------------------------
| service_id | other_service_columns | user_id |
-----------------------------------------------|
|     23     |       other data      |    14   |
|     24     |       other data      |    14   |
------------------------------------------------


Table: service_categories
---------------------------------------
| service_cat_id | cat_id | service_id|
---------------------------------------
|        1       |   924  |     23    |
|        2       |   863  |     23    |
|        3       |   506  |     24    |
|        4       |   510  |     24    |
---------------------------------------

Table: categories
---------------------
| cat_id | cat_name |
---------------------
|   924  | cleaning |
|   863  | washing  |
|   506  | drying   |
|   510  | scrubbing|
---------------------
```

Table 4 might not have any results, so I'm doing a left join. However when I group by service_id, I'm not getting all the relevant categories from the 'service_categories' and 'categories' tables - just one row is returned in the query. Is group_concat the answer? If so, I'm not sure how to use this to get the result I need - i.e. all relevant categories returned in the query. Please help!

I need to be able to process the query result by iterating over it using foreach, to produce something in the view like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| Service ID | Other Service Data | Service Categories |
--------------------------------------------------------
|     23     | Data for Service 23| cleaning, washing  |
|     24     | Data for Service 24| drying, scrubbing  |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** based on your comments and updated question your base SQL query might look like

```sql
SELECT s.*, q.categories, t4.*
  FROM services s LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT sc.service_id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name) categories
    FROM service_categories sc JOIN categories c 
      ON sc.cat_id= c.cat_id
   GROUP BY sc.service_id
) q ON s.service_id = q.service_id LEFT JOIN table4 t4
    ON s.service_id = t4.service_id
 WHERE s.user_id = ?
```

Sample output:

```
| SERVICE_ID | OTHER_SERVICE_COLUMNS | USER_ID |       CATEGORIES |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|         23 |            other data |      14 | cleaning,washing |
|         24 |            other data |      14 | drying,scrubbing |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b00a/10)** demo

Now a possible version of CI code

```php
$sql = "SELECT s.*, q.categories, t4.*
          FROM services s LEFT JOIN
        (
          SELECT sc.service_id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name) categories
            FROM service_categories sc JOIN categories c 
              ON sc.cat_id= c.cat_id
           GROUP BY sc.service_id
        ) q ON s.service_id = q.service_id LEFT JOIN table4 t4
            ON s.service_id = t4.service_id
         WHERE s.user_id = $user_id";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
   ...
}
```

**Answer to the original question:**
IMHO there are several issues with your query

1. You're limiting your resultset to the only `service_id` with `WHERE` clause. Therefore `GROUP BY services.service_id` and `ORDER BY services.service_id` makes no sense. `GROUP_BY` can make sense only if you want to pack values into delimited strings and get back the only row.
2. You're not using `LIMIT` therefore `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` also makes no sense.

That being said you query might look like

```php
$result = $this->db
     ->select('services.*
        ,service_categories.*
        ,categories.*
        ,table4.*', FALSE)
     ->from('services')
     ->join('service_categories', 'service_categories.service_id = services.service_id')
     ->join('categories', 'categories.cat_id= service_categories.cat_id')
     ->join('table4', 'table4.service_id= services.service_id', 'left')
     ->where('services.service_id', $service_id)
     ->get();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/090c0/3)** demo

Comment: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is probably not relevant to the question, but I'm using it in the query because I need to calculate the number of found results. I'm returning the count as part of the query using $data['count'] = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() count;')->row()->count; However without grouping, the number of returned rows is equal to the number of service_categories rather than the number of services. Actually I made an error in the question too - apologies- should have been ->where('services.user_id', $user_id)

Comment: You can get the number of records returned by `count($result)` without hitting database second time. Now can you edit your question and show what is your desired output based on sample data that you provided?

Comment: Ok thankyou for your help, I have edited the question to show the desired output